# How to increment & decrements values in django templete based on condition

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2, counter

Hi I'm new in django I have counter=0 in for loop based on condition I need to increment or decrements that value

```
{{ variable|add='1' }}
```

I try to use this but after 1st time increment the value remain constant for all the iteration of the loop

I also see that some people use custom tag & filter but I'm not able to understand that how it will work and how can I made my custom tag 
Is there is someone who can help me to make my custom tag of increment & decrements or help me to solve my issue

my_code

```
{% for i in posts %}
    {% if counter == i %}
       ....
       ....
       ....
       {{ counter |add='1' }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Increment** the counter. it will print like:1,2,3

```
{% for i in posts %}
   <p>{{ forloop.counter}}Iteration - {{ i }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

For **decrements** the counter. it will print like:3,2,1

```
{% for i in posts %}
   <p>{{ forloop.revcounter }} Iteration - {{ i }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: no i had to increment value no certain condition not for all the time
for example my condition will true on when ```{% for x in range %} {% if forloop.counter == 10 %} {{counter=counter+1 }} {% endif  %} {% endfor %}```